# Ajax call sometimes doesnt print content

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I made an AJAX filter for woocommerce, which filters products based on attributes.

The query works fine, and it always prints the right products and content. That it actually prints something.

Every once i a while it will run but not add any html. If i log the data received it's clearly there. Sometimes the `html()` function just doesnt do anything.

It seems the error occurs more often if i doubleclick the filter button before it's done with its previous operation. I've tried adding a data attribute to check if the ajax is done filtering, to stop any calls from happening before the first is done. It doesn't seem to really work though.

The AJAX function:

```
function getPosts(page){
var filter = $('#filter');

if(filter.length < 1){
    return false;
}
if(filter.data('loading') == true){
    return false;
}
var buttonText = $('#filter #product-ajax-submit').text();
$.ajax({
    url:filter.attr('action'),
    data:filter.serialize() + '&page=' + page, // form data
    type:filter.attr('method'), // POST
    dataType: 'json',

    beforeSend:function(xhr){
        filter.attr('data-loading', true);
        filter.find('#product-ajax-submit').text('Filtrerer...'); // changing the button label

        $('#bbh-ajax-loader').fadeIn(200, function(){

            var productsHeight = $('ul.products').outerHeight();
            $('ul.products').parent().css('height', productsHeight);
            $('ul.products').html(''); // delete current content
            $('.woocommerce-pagination').html('');
        });

    },
    success:function(data){

        $('ul.products').empty().append(data[0]);
        filter.find('#product-ajax-submit').text(buttonText); // changing the button label back

        $('.woocommerce-pagination').html(data[1]);

        $('ul.products').parent().css('height', 'auto');
        $('#bbh-ajax-loader').fadeOut(300);

        filter.find('select, button').prop( "disabled", false );

    },
    error:function(data){
        $('ul.products').html(data.responseText);
        $('ul.products').parent().css('height', 'auto');

        $('#bbh-ajax-loader').fadeOut(300);
         // insert data
        filter.find('#product-ajax-submit').text(buttonText);


    },
    complete:function(data){
        filter.attr('data-loading', false);
    }
});
}

$('#filter[data-live-sort="false"]').on('submit', function(){

    getPosts(1);
    return false;
});
```

As I said, if I log the returned data, the markup is always correct. Both on success and error. I suspect maybe clearing the html from `ul.products` on `beforeSend` could create problems with the success data being displayed if multiple calls are made simultaniously.

Comment: Not sure it's related, but it's somewhat risky to access `data` by index directly without doing any checks on it (for example, where you've got `.html(data[1])` ) - you might put in some defensive checks and `console.log(data)` if `data.length < 2`, for example.

Comment: Yeah defensive checks are a good idea. But when i `console.log(data)` it always returns the right data. Just sometimes the `html(data[1])` function doesn't write anything.